# RFC SAP table connector (Azure Data Factory): TIMESTAMP column ACDOCA

Tags: azure-data-factory

I want to use the RFC options of the SAP table connector in Azure Data Factory. More specifically I want to filter on the TIMESTAMP column (from ACDOCA table) so that I can perform an incremental load. The following query is constructed, but keeps on giving errors.

[image: Error result]

The RFC option is created as follows:

[image: Query construction]

Is there a way to change this so that it works? It works for all other date columns (BUDAT,...)

I tried changing the query but nothing seems to solve the error.

Comment: Could you share the error message?

Comment: I received the following error: Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=SapRfcClientOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=SapRfcClient operation '/SAPDS/RFC_READ_TABLE2' failed. Please contact SAP support if you need further help. Error message: 'An error has occurred while parsing a dynamic entry.',Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.SapRfcHelper,''Type=SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcAbapRuntimeException,Message=An error has occurred while parsing a dynamic entry.,Source=sapnco,'